# Max and sum on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, max

I have the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'In':['A','B','D','Z','Q','E'],
                   'Out' : ['Z', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'Z', 'A'],
                   'Score_in' : ['6', '2', '1', '0', '1', '3'], 
                   'Score_out' : ['2','3','0', '1','1','3'],
                   'Place' : ['One','Two','Four', 'Two','Two','One']})
```

I would like to get two outputs:

1. how many scored point are in each Place?
2. which is the "place" where there were the most point (the sum of it) scored?

Let's assume that I have more than one df like this or, which is the same, a "year" column where I groupby to filter the championship I want. How could I plot the required output for each year where on the x label there are places, year and on the y label there is the number of scored points?

Comment: Nate, you're asking a bunch of questions, and I would break them into separate SO posts / questions. As to the first question of groupby - could you please include the required output?

Comment: You are right Roy, I apologize. Here the broken related question, if you could please help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568580/plot-with-for-cycle-on-pandas

Comment: Sure. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer to the first question:

```
df["Score_out"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Score_out"])
df["Score_in"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Score_in"])
res = df.assign(total = df.Score_in + df.Score_out).groupby("Place").sum()
print(res) 

#output: 

       Score_in  Score_out  total
Place                            
Four          1          0      1
One           9          5     14
Two           3          5      8

res.sort_values("total", ascending = False).index[0]
```

output:

```
'One'
```

Answer (score 0):

For summing score, you can use groupby:

```
>>> df.groupby('Place')['Score_in', 'Score_out'].sum()
       Score_in  Score_out
Place                     
Four          1          0
One           9          5
Two           3          5
```

For total sum:

```
>>> temp = df.groupby('Place')['Score_in', 'Score_out'].sum().sum(axis = 1)
>>> temp
Place
Four     1
One     14
Two      8
dtype: int64
```

For getting maximum:

```
>>> temp[temp == temp.max()]
Place
One    14
dtype: int64
```