# Plot with for cycle on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Let's assume that I have a df with a "Date" column to use to filter the championship I want and that I did it by setting "Date" column as index. Moreover, I have a function to configure all column types as I want:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['26-12-2018','26-12-2018','27-12-2018','27-12-2018','28-12-2018','28-12-2018'],
                   'In':['A','B','D','Z','Q','E'],
                   'Out' : ['Z', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'Z', 'A'],
                   'Score_in' : ['6', '2', '1', '0', '1', '3'], 
                   'Score_out' : ['2','3','0', '1','1','3'],
                   'Place' : ['One','Two','Four', 'Two','Two','One']})
```

Could I plot on the same plot - as it was a grid - for instance:

```
df.groupby('In').Score_in.sum().add(df.groupby('Out').Score_out.sum())
```

with a for cycle for each day by passing the function parameter "day" as iterator?
I don't understand how well, something like:

```
for it in range(26:28:1):

    if it == day:
        ..plot_settings.. f(it)
```

Comment: unrelated:  `range(26:28:1)` ?  `range(26,28,1)`? or `[26,27]` ?

Comment: Could you please explain what kind of chart (plot) would you like to have in the end? The total score per day over X days, as a line chart? Something else?

Comment: I thought more as histogram instead of line chart. It would be feasible something as hexbin format?

Comment: Histogram of what? Can you add the desired output (even as a photo of a sketch at the back of a napkin) to the question?

Comment: Maybe it is more correct to think to a bar chart where the on the x label there are teams and on the y label total score, but I would like to do it with a for cycle so I can have it for each day on the same grid

Comment: The teams are A, B, C, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a piece of code that builds a matplotlib plot of your data. It should be noted that as far as I can tell, matplotlib isn't the most friendly package for this kind of plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates 

df["score"] = pd.to_numeric(df["score"])
df = df.groupby(["Date", "team"]).sum()
df = df.reset_index()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

groups = df.Date.unique()
num_groups = len(groups)

ind = np.arange(num_groups)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.10                   # the width of the bars

days = pd.date_range(df.Date.min(), df.Date.max(), freq = "1D")

rect_list = []
for inx, t in enumerate(df.team.unique()) :
    sub_df = df[df.team == t]
    sub_df = sub_df.set_index("Date").reindex(days)

    x_locations = ind + width * inx
    rects = ax.bar(x_locations, sub_df.score, width, bottom = 0)
    rect_list.append(rects)

ax.legend(rect_list, df.team.unique())
        
ax.set_xticks(ind + width*2)

labels = [pd.to_datetime(x).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for x in groups]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

fig.show()
```

The result is:

[image]

If you prefer to have each day in a separate plot, you can do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.dates as mdates 

df["score"] = pd.to_numeric(df["score"])
df = df.groupby(["Date", "team"]).sum()
df = df.reset_index()

days = df.Date.unique()

fig, subplots = plt.subplots(len(days), 1)

all_teams = df.team.unique()

for d, ax in zip(days, subplots):

    sub_df = df[df.Date == d]
    
    sub_df.set_index("team", inplace=True)
    sub_df = sub_df.reindex(all_teams).sort_index().fillna(value = 0)
    
    rects = ax.bar(sub_df.index, sub_df.score, width, bottom = 0)
    ax.set_title(pd.to_datetime(d).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Roy! It is really near what I was looking for: is there a way to have separated plots for each day on a gridplot, instead of all on the same plot?

Comment: Thank you for your editing Roy! I have the last doubt: I get what do you mean for df["score"] which is df["Score_in"] + df["Score_out"], but I how can I find what you named df["team"]?

Comment: Team is the original "In" and "out" (A, B, C, etc).